# Generating Input Cases from x-axis and y-axis in a Given Table using Cucumber-Java

Tags: spring-boot, bdd, cucumber-java

I am using Cucumber-Java to write test cases and I am wondering if it is possible to generate all input cases from the x-axis and y-axis of a given table and then assert that the output matches the value in (x, y).

For example, suppose I have the following table:

```
x\y | 0 | 1 | 2 |
A | A0 | A1 | A2 |
B | B0 | B1 | B2 |
C | C0 | C1 | C2 |
```

With a certain syntax, I would like Cucumber to help me generate the following 9 test cases:

```
(A, 0) -> A0
(A, 1) -> A1
(A, 2) -> A2
(B, 0) -> B0
(B, 1) -> B1
(B, 2) -> B2
(C, 0) -> C0
(C, 1) -> C1
(C, 2) -> C2
```

This would be very helpful to ensure test coverage when the input space is large. So my question is, is it possible to achieve this using Cucumber-Java, and if so, how?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Gherkin is not a programming language. So you'd write it down like you just did:

```
Scenario: Pairwise combinations
  * The system supports all pairwise combinations
    x\y | 0  | 1  | 2  |
      A | A0 | A1 | A2 |
      B | B0 | B1 | B2 |
      C | C0 | C1 | C2 |
```

And then inside your step definition you loop over all rows and columns of the table and assert that for the given inputs X and Y, the output is as expected.